# Not able to attach google form in my website when using helmet

Tags: node.js, forms, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I am not able to attach the google form to my website while using helmet js. What could be the code to allow it?

**iframe**

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/..." width="600" height="850px" class="col-12" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
```

**Helmet Middleware**

```
app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            frameSrc: ["'self'", "https://docs.google.com/forms"],
        }
    },
}));
```

**Error on Client-Side**

> Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/forms' because it violates
> the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".
> Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
> as a fallback.

Comment: It looks like you're setting the `frame-src` directive but your browser doesn't notice. Have you tried clearing your browser cache? What is the value of the `Content-Security-Policy` header in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @EvanHahn It was actually. I posted the solution below which works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution.

We need to set COEP (Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) response header if we want to embed any link with the website.

```
app.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            "frame-ancestors": ["'self'", "*.google.com/"],
            frameSrc: ["'self'", "*.google.com/"],
            childSrc: ["'self'", "*.google.com/"]
        }
    },
    // crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "cross-origin")
    next()
})
```

Comment: Please try to explain a little bit about your solution for fellow developers and help seekers to better understand it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).